# Mockito allow mocked return value to be set

Tags: java, mockito

Is it possible to change the value that is returned from a mocked object?

Below is an example that explains what I am trying to do.

```
public class MyClass{
  public void method(Mock obj){
    if(obj.getValue.equals("value"){
      obj.setValue("changedValue");
    }

    anotherObj.call(obj.getValue());
  }
```

So the above class is very simplified.  It will change the value returned if the value passed in equals value.

```
@Test
public void test(){
  Mock obj = mock(Mock.class);
  when(obj.getValue()).thenReturn("value");

  testClass.method(obj);

  verify(anotherObj, times(1)).call("changedValue");
}
```

The test want to verify that the anotherObj.call is called with the changed value, but since we have mocked the return value to be 'value' this will fail as 'value' is returned.

Is it possible to create a test using a mocked returnValue?

Comment: Calling verify on anotherObj would imply that anotherObj is also a mock, but this is not specified in your example. Please update it to reflect your exact test case

Comment: Looks like the only way is like said below is to not mock the object but to actually create an instance of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Johnatan is right. If `obj` is not a complex object, you can avoid mocking it and use a real one.

If for some reason this is not possible, mockito allows to define a series of answers, eg: `when(obj.getValue()).thenReturn("value").thenReturn("modifiedValue");` which could be what you are looking for.

Although it might be overkill, just to make sure that all was ok, I would also `verify(obj).setValue("changedValue");` and `verify(obj, times(2)).getValue();`

Comment: Your first snippet there can be written more simply as `when(obj.getValue()).thenReturn("value","modifiedValue");` - you can provide as many arguments as you like to `thenReturn`, provided they are all of the appropriate type.  The first one is returned the first time the stubbed method is called, then the second one, and so on.  The last value that you provide will be returned repeatedly, once all the other values have been used up.

Answer (score 4):

Would this suffice?

```
    ObjectUnderTest objectUnderTest = new ObjectUnderTest();
    ObjectUnderTest spy2 = Mockito.spy(objectUnderTest);

    when(spy2.getValue()).thenAnswer(new Answer<String>() {

        @Override
        public String answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
            Object realAnswer = invocation.callRealMethod();
            if (realAnswer.equals("SOME VALUE")) {
                return "SOME OTHER VALUE";
            }else {
                return realAnswer;
            }
        }
    });
```

So when the real getValue returns some value you can replace that with a different value...

Answer (score 2):

Instead of mocking `obj`, why not use the actual implementation? Then presumably the `setValue` and `getValue` methods would work as you would expect.

Although I appreciate this might not be possible, as you have mentioned your example is a much simplified version of your actual problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@Test
public void test(){
  Mock obj = mock(Mock.class);

  doCallRealMethod().when(obj).setValue(any(String.class));
  when(obj.getValue()).thenCallRealMethod();
  obj.setValue("value");

  testClass.method(obj);

  verify(anotherObj, times(1)).call("changedValue");
}
```